# How to update data of a field in an oracle table?

Tags: shell-script, sql

My table name: KEY_PARAMETER
It consists two fields named SET_NO. and MES_VAL
SET_NO. is fixed which doesn't change but my MES_VAL filed is getting changed is every on minute.

My intention is to update this MES_VAL field without deleting its old value.

```
SQL> desc key_parameter;
SQL> select SET_NO and MES_VAL from key_parameter;

SET_NO. MES_VAL
------  -------
2324     12.22
5555     -90.40
65467    89.98
1243     123
6754     12.67
5677     898.55
7853     11.00
9865     449.12
3244     90.33
3545     76.89
```

After one minute, when the MES_VAL field will be updated. It should be like this.

```
SET_NO. MES_VAL
------  -------
2324     17.67
5555     -90.5
65467    34,88
1243     88
6754     32,90
5677     227.9
7853     30.6
9865     109.3
3244     23.40
3545     132.8
```

In the back end, a Unix shell script is running in my Solaris system. Where my updated data is getting saved in a .txt file. I have tried using oracle sqlldr REPLACE command, but what is happening it is deleting it's data and then new data is getting populated into table. For the time being, operator are unable to view any data until new value is getting inserted.

Also I have tried insert into command but what is happening instead of updating the field, it keeps the old data which I don't required.

Comment: You mean you don't know aoout the "update" statement?  As in "update key_parameter set mes_val = 17.67 where set_no = 2324".

Comment: In every minute I cannot do it manually. It has to done automatically. My system will check the value of it's corresponding set_no. and then update it into table.

Comment: How did you run the sqlldr?  What is "your system"?

Comment: solaris v5.8 /u01/app/oracle/product/8.1.7/sqlldr hfdora/hfdora@hfd2 control=/home/test.ctrl

Comment: So, what do you have at your disposal to automate this old timer?  Only shell and sqlplus, or do you have a C compiler so we can use Pro*C ?  How do you obtain the new data?  And you said the Solaris was the "backend".   What system is the "frontend"?

Comment: my system runs a shell script in crontab. saves data in text file. and through sqlldr it imports data into my oaracle table.

Comment: We could modify your script to generate an SQL script with update statements, and start SQL\*Plus to execute them.  More performant would be to have SQL\*Loader load the data into a "temporary" table, and start a stored procedure to update the base table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked.

```
cat /tmp/spec2PC_sc.txt | sed -e 's/[insert]*/insert into key_parameter (SET_NO,MES_VAL) values (/' | sed 's/.*/&);/' >> /tmp/spec2PC1.txt
```